# Update Column Data of Table Aliases According to other Column's Data

Tags: sql-server

I have a store Procedure as Following

```
BEGIN
    ;with Data as(
    select 
    E.Id,
    E.FirstName as [Employee],
    E.IsDeleted AS [status],
    Co.Name as [Company],
    S.SalaryType,
    S.Date as [Date],
    E.Desc as Notes,
    CASE @SortField
        WHEN 'Id' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E.Id)
        WHEN 'date' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S.Date)
    END rn
    From Employee E
    Inner Join Company Co on E.CompId = Co.Id
    Inner Join Salary S on E.Salarytype = S.Id
    Where 
    E.Name Like '%'+@EmployeeName+'%'
    -- Other AND Conditions --
    )
    select *,(Select Count(1) From data) FilteredCount -- can i Update it here ??--
    FROM data
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN rn else -rn END  
    OFFSET @StartIndex ROWS  
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY 
END
```

It of course Gives more columns in result but to keep question short i kept only two columns.

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Status| 
+------+-------+
| John | 1     | 
| Mark | 1     | 
| Sami | 0     | 
+------+-------+
```

So now I just want some changes in my table aliases so I can update result SET Name = 'Deleted' Where I am getting Status as 0

```
+--------+-------+
| Name   | Status| 
+--------+-------+
| John   | 1     | 
| Mark   | 1     | 
| Deleted| 0     | 
+------+---------+
```

Is this possible to update Table aliases an perform `Order by` Like Operations on it ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a CTE to `UPDATE` the table, or even get the result set you require, but you can `OUTPUT` the column of a table you `UPDATE` at the same time you `UPDATE` it. *Normally* for the above, however, you would only `UPDATE` the rows you want to `UPDATE`, rather than them all, though that doesn't mean you *can't*:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.Employee
SET [Name] = CASE Status WHEN 1 THEN [Name] ELSE 'Deleted' END
OUTPUT inserted.[Name],
       inserted.Status;
```

Comment: @Larmu, see my small query as a big store procedure where I perform sorting at the end after selecting `*` from my table Alease.. so is there any way I can achieve that also from this.. i.e `ORDER BY Data.Name`

Comment: Putting a *meaningful* example in the question helps, @MaulikDave . If the code you have given isn't representative of the problem, edit your question so it is. Also `UPDATE` statements don't have `ORDER BY` clauses.